# Convert a directory of JPEG files to a single PDF document

Tags: command-line, pdf, conversion, jpeg

I have many JPEG files in a directory, and I want to convert them to PDF and concatenate them together to make a single document.

How can this be done?

I would prefer using the command line, as this process will be faster.

Comment: unfortunately this question not accepting answers any more, but give `pdfcpu` a try  it's written in `go` so it's a single binary and have simple cli interface

Answer (score 514):

From the `imagemagick` package, use the `convert` command:

```
convert *.jpg -auto-orient pictures.pdf
```

You will get a single pdf containing all jpg in the current folder.
The option `-auto-orient` reads the image's EXIF data to rotate the image.

Install IM with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

sources: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955425/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-images-to-a-pdf-from-the-command-line-on-linux)
[imagemagick options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient)

Edit: Note that images will be out of specific order if they are not numbered. if you have 10 or more you need to name them ending filename01.jpg...filename99.jpg etc. The leading zeros are required for proper ordering. If you have 100 or more 001...999.

Comment: Using the joker didn't work for me, I had to use @Alex's solution.

Comment: @Eusebius if the wildcard doesn't work for you with convert, you could use a oneliner like `for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" "$f.pdf"; done; pdftk *.pdf cat output final.pdf`

Comment: `GrphicMagick` users should run `gm convert *.jpg pictures.pdf`

Comment: Maybe my jpg files are too big and numerous, but doing that almost immediately consumed so much RAM that my 16GB system started swapping.

Comment: Note that this method may now result in a `not authorized` error; [see this related question (and answers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert).

Comment: I got one of these errors for every file: convert-im6.q16: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c/ConnectPixelCacheServer/244.
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted `A-217.JPG' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3984.  I tried the img2pdf (suggested below and it worked)

Comment: Same as @RonJohn, using 'convert' kills my RAM, even for just a few images...

Comment: @JaniUusitalo, thank You for Your comment. I would encourage You to just edit the answer and include it as it seems crucial to make it all work.

Comment: any idea how to make convert take into account the rotation from exif?

Comment: @Kostanos: use the option -auto-orient. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Does 'convert' keep all the image details such as the image resolution, JPEG quality, etc by default? Read the man page and did not find anything about it. Thank you!

Comment: @Maxim: Yes it does. To reduce the resolution I used "convert *.jpg -auto-orient -quality 75% pictures.pdf" to drop image quality to 75%.

Comment: I don't know why, but it only works fine for the first 3-4 images out of ~180... The rest are blank pages.

Comment: Will this be lossless?

Comment: @einpoklum: according to scarlacii's comment, it is. You will have to use e.g. -quality 75% to change that.

Answer (score 176):

Unfortunately, `convert` changes the image quality before "packing it" into the PDF. So, to have minimal loss of quality, it is better to put the original `jpg` (or `.png`) into the PDF.  To do this, you need to use `img2pdf` as follows:

(Updated as suggested in the comments) A shorter *one line solution* using `img2pdf`:

1. Make PDF

   ```
   img2pdf *.jp* --output combined.pdf
   ```
2. (Optionally) OCR the output PDF

   ```
   ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf
   ```

---

Below is the *original* answer with more commands and more tools needed:

1. This command is to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

   ```
   ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
   ```
2. This command will concatenate the `pdf` pages into one document:

   ```
   pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
   ```
3. And finally, I add an OCRed text layer that doesn't change the quality of the scan in the pdfs so that they can be searchable:

   ```
   pypdfocr combined.pdf
   ```

   Or, as an alternative to using `pypdfocr`:

   ```
   ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf
   ```

Comment: Great method! The only disadvantage without compression would be that the resulting .pdf filesize will be very high (that is, slightly larger than all pics combined). But worth it if the document you're converting is really an important one!

Comment: This worked fine after `convert` failed with "attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF'".

Comment: `img2pdf` support inputing simultaneously many JPEGs. See examples in its manpage.

Comment: img2pdf *.jpeg --output jpegsas.pdf did the trick for me, no piping or multiple steps, ordering was correct. I don't care about ocr though, but that coud be added easily. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthiasBraun That is addressed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081695/error-during-converting-jpg-to-pdf

Comment: You may have to install some `tesseract-ocr-` package(s) to support OCR of your language(s).

Comment: This makes the trick! Especially combined with [jpegoptim](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/how-to-optimize-jpeg-command-line-linux) to first control the size of the input pictures, for example: `jpegoptim --overwrite --size=1000k *.jp*`

Comment: To retain lossless-ness with `ocrmypdf`, use: `ocrmypdf --optimize 0 --output-type pdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf`

Answer (score 42):

```
convert `ls -1v` file.pdf
```

- This ls will list one file a time in a "natural order" (1,2,3...) and proceed with conversion.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. numerous errors indicate that it might have something to do with spaces in the filenames.

Comment: To take care of the spaces issue, perform a pattern replacement first: 
    for ThisFile in *.jpg; do mv "$ThisFile" "${ThisFile// /_}" >/dev/null 2>&1; d

Answer (score 30):

Worked for me (BUT warning! `+compress` options **turns off compression** and resulting PDF will be big!):

```
convert page1.jpg page2.jpg +compress file.pdf
```

or even:

```
convert -rotate 90 page\*.jpg +compress file.pdf
```

From ubuntuforums.org, the `+compress` helps it to not hang.
NOTE: the +compress turns off compression. The machine I was working on at the time seemed to hang ?forever?(I did not wait forever though to find out.) without the +compress option. Your Mileage May Vary quite a bit! RTFM on [imagemagick.org option -compress](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress), maybe experiment with -compress < type> if you have slow compression/hanging problems to find out what will work for you.

Comment: Do NOT use the `+compress` option with the `convert` command as suggested above! It actually disables all compression leaving you with a PDF 10 times bigger than the original JPEG. Just don't specify compression options, and `convert` will go with the input compression format (JPEG) which in this case is the best option file size-wise. Source: [http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress)

Comment: That is not intuitive! Thanks S Minddal. That did work for me. I presume the machine I was using had a problem doing the compression then. I will adjust answer.

Comment: so `$ converet *.jpg file.pdf` worked well with smaller file size than with `+compress` argument

Answer (score 21):

I'm curious nobody pointed out pdfjam, which is a super efficient way to merge images/pdf into a pdf:

```
pdfjam --a4paper *.jpg
```

will create for you a pdf in A4 format for all `.jpg` files, usually named with a `-pdfjam.pdf` at the end. To force a specific output name, you have a `--outfile <your output>` option!

As far as I can see, there is no re-encoding of the file, making the command pretty fast compared to `convert`.

To install pdfjam, I'm not sure to know what's the most efficient way (it comes automatically with LaTeX), but you can try:

```
sudo apt install pdfjam
```

or maybe

```
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

Comment: This did the job for me!

Comment: Liked the A4 format, but not worth the 400MB install of the texlive-extra-utils... Good answer, tho

Comment: Did not work for me. `pdfjam: FAILED. The call to /usr/bin/pdflatex resulted in an error`

Comment: @mishadr weird. Maybe create another question with more details, in particular the full log.

Comment: Excellent little program. Exactly what I was looking for. Definitely worth the extra 400MB (see comment above)

Comment: @DAB you can pass `-page A4` in `convert`. img2pdf have similar feature as well.

Answer (score 15):

Open jpg or png file with LibreOffice Writer and export as PDF.

I hope, this is simple way to export pdf.

Comment: might also try `google'ing`, a lot of online converter website

Answer (score 7):

The following solution also relies on ImageMagick's `convert` but is a bit more sophisticated because:

- It allows all images to have different dimensions, while keeping the output PDF page size the same (A4 in the example below).
- It centers the images on the PDF page.
- It allows you to guarantee a minimum space between image borders and PDF page borders, to allow printing the PDF without problems.
- It does not change the image data. (So image quality is unaffected, the PDF file has about the same file size as the image, and you can re-extract the original images later with [`pdfimages -j file.pdf img`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html).) At the moment, this only works with PNG – see the comment by @dma_k below.

Instructions:

1. Use my script from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220114/18163) to convert each image into its own one-page PDF file with A4 page size and 5% border all around.
2. Concatenate all your one-page PDF files with PDFtk as follows:

   ```
   pdftk *.pdf cat output out.pdf
   ```

Comment: This command shows that (at least with the versions supplied on Ubuntu 16.04) image data *is* affected: `convert some.jpg -format pdf -compress jpeg generated.pdf ; pdfimages -j generated.pdf generated.pdf ; diff -sq some.jpg generated.pdf-000.jpg`

Comment: I was playing with GraphicsMagick and I have noticed that *it performs image recompression*. The quality of the resulting JPEG image on PDF page is much worse. So at the moment the safest way is to add PNG images – they are inserted correctly. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/473674/164142) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using *`img2pdf`* you can do that.
 But sometimes you may need your images converted to document in an order by timestamp or by size or by name.To make that possible this script does that work.

`ls -trQ | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\ --output\ mydoc.pdf/' | xargs img2pdf`

In place of mydoc.pdf, enter name of output file as your wish.

Option of `ls` command( instead of `-tr` use these as per your need)

- `-S` ,  sort by file size, largest first
- `-t`   ,  sort by modification time, newest first
- `-X`  ,   sort alphabetically by entry extension
- `-r` , reverse order while sorting

Answer (score 0):

Although convert does the job, it tries to open all the source files together and if you have a lot of files and do not have a huge amount of RAM you can run out it.

So as an alternative you can run the following commands in a terminal while being in the folder where the jpg files are.

```
ls *.jpg | xargs -I% img2pdf -o %.pdf %
```

This converts each image to a single page pdf, one by one, without overloading the system. Then:

```
pdfunite *.pdf output.pdf && rm *.jpg.pdf
```

This merges the pdfs into a single pdf and deletes the single page ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is humblesome - but file-size can explode - to avoid exploding
file-size you can do these steps :

a)
At first you need to export with "gimp" the *.jpeg-files to *.jpg-files.
(jpeg is Apple format - jpeg and jpg are both NOT the same !).
jpg-file would need a small white or black 'passepartout' (=frame).

b)
With Android and app "photocompress" I compress the jpg files to
size under 300 KBytes each.

c)
then back to Desktop of Ubuntu you can edit these files with
Libre-Office and create a pdf-map with them.

Surely somebody knows how this works from a) to c) simply in terminal ?

The side-effect of this is, that it can happen, because of correct byte-size
the recipient with bad $mickrosaft has then posters, but it is not your fault.

Comment: It's much simpler than that, you can use jpegoptim to control the size of the pictures, for example: `jpegoptim --overwrite --size=1000k *.jp*`