# Error during converting jpg to pdf

Tags: pdf, convert

Each time I want to convert `jpg` file to `pdf` by this command

```
convert *.jpg pictures.pdf
```

I have this error message:

```
convert: not authorized `pictures.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028.
```

Comment: convert *.jpg pictures.pdf will overwrite all pdf files as one file pictures.pdf?

Comment: This solution from StackOverflow worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This problems comes from a security update:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13

Someone reported it as a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1796563

As a temporary fix, I edited `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and changed the PDF rights from `none` to `read|write` there. Not sure about the implications, but at least it allows me to get things done.

Comment: I looked into it again, and I'm almost certain that the security fix is related to   https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928 (which documents various ways to bypass -dSAFER in ghostscript).

Comment: This indeed works as advertized. I simply commented out (effectively removed) the pdf-line. It would be good to know what the side-effects would be! The policymap in the config file comments that this is for "disable ghostscript format types".

Comment: See also: https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/pdf-not-authorized.html

Comment: I was hesitant to change the security settings. As an alternative to imagemagick I used "pdftoppm -jpeg input.pdf output.jpg" (from package named poppler-utils). This alternative was posted in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1796563

Comment: Change destination file format policy respectively <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" /> .Usually they will be at the end .Thanks

Comment: Or you can just edit:
/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
AND comment by using <!-- and -->
the line: 
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
which becomes:
<!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" /> -->

Comment: Worked brilliantly for me

Answer (score 28):

Fixed this on my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and 18.04.6 LTS by following [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081724/66509).

Created simple sed one-liner to get this fixed faster:

`sudo sed -i 's#<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />#<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />#' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

and in programmatic way.

Answer (score 7):

If you're worried about the implications, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1796563 mentions that

> While the release notes are not exactly *clear*, Ghostscript v9.25 seems to make reference to fixing some vulnerabilities of this sort: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/News.htm

Answer (score 4):

**Disabling security limitations is a bad habit to get into.** The ImageMagick authors presumably made this one for a reason. You should respect that, unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. That does not seem probable for most people looking at these answers.

The right thing to do in this case is to use other software which the authors themselves believe to be secure.

Here `img2pdf` fits the bill:

```
img2pdf --output out.pdf in.jpg
```

Comment: How does disrupting the normal `convert` command make your computer more secure?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is to convert *to* PDF.

Comment: @ReinierPost Well noticed, thanks! Answer corrected.

Comment: @Sqerstet: Thanks! I just tried it and it does exactly what I needed (it can create both an unresized version and a resized version for printing).

Comment: @ReinierPost So stop saying thanks and just give me a point :)

Comment: This works and seems to get the resolution right without any extra options.

Comment: also img2pdf fails due to the same policy on install