# tensorflow import error 1037

Tags: tensorflow

Let me say this right in the very beginning, I am new to this and I have no idea what is to be done.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04. And I am positive I have all the prerequisites for tensorflow installed.

I tried two different ways of installing tensorflow, one that was on the official website, and the other using conda.

Either-way, when I use

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

in the virtual environment, I get the following exact error:

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `tf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

I searched a lot and I tried but there's no question I can find with this error code. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it's related to [Error during converting jpg to pdf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081695/error-during-converting-jpg-to-pdf) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke python from your shell before the import statement.

```
$ python
```

then,

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `python3` first to start the python3 interpreter in interactive mode, then import tensorflow.

If `import tensorflow as tf` is in a script either add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of your script or run the script as `python3 script.py`