# auto install email attachments to file?

Tags: server, pdf, email, mutt

I'm semi-new to Linux and ubuntu. I'm setting up a Linux server for a small office that doubles as a network drive. I'm trying to find a software that will take all email attachments and save them to a folder for use on the network drive. So far I'm using mutt, but I don't think I have the option to save it as a pdf. Would anybody happen to know how to do this? I'm using lubuntu due to it having a lightweight interface.

Comment: Are you running your own mail server (postfix?) or are you connecting to a server such as `gmail.com`?

Comment: gmail.com, though only because I don't quite understand postfix. Does that work even if they aren't on the same network?

Comment: So... you use something like Thunderbird to read your emails, correct? I don't know how you could auto-save the attachments from a client. A server would have hooks where you can add a script which does such things.

Comment: I was hoping to use something like mutt as an email client, then to have it auto-download all emails that got sent to it. I would like to make a server, but how much would that cost to be able to email it anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am not sure the detail, but `imagemagick` `convert` `lowrite` use these commands, you get some PDFs from pictures and documents. I don't know where they are stored and am reluctant to write a practical script but yeah it's possible. https://askubuntu.com/questions/246647/convert-a-directory-of-jpeg-files-to-a-single-pdf-document